# SUBSTRING_INDEX in HANA

Tags: mysql, hana

I'm migrating the database engine an application from MySql to SAP HANA.

I found a little trouble. I have a query like this:

```
Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, "-", -2) as prod_ref From products;
```

I don't know how to "translate" the function `substring_index`, because the initial part of the `id` has a variable length.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a regex:

```
 select substr_regexpr( '.*-([^-]*-[^-]*)$' in 'varia-ble---part-part1-part2' group 1) from dummy;
 select substr_regexpr( '.*-([^-]*-[^-]*)$' in 'variable-part-part1-part2' group 1) from dummy;
```

According to the HANA 2.0 SP0 doc you could use locate with a negative offset (and then using right()), but this does not work on my system ("...feature isn't supported...")

If you execute such queries on a regular basis on lots of records I would recommend extracting the part you are interested in during ETL into a separate field. Or, alternatively fill a separate field using " GENERATED ALWAYS AS...".
I have seen it more than once, that people calculate a field like this in complex SQL queries or complex CalcViews, and then wonder why performance is bad when selecting 100 million records and filtering on the calculated field etc... Performance is usually no problem when you have aggregated your intermediate result set to a reasonable size and then apply "expensive" functions.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any direct function like SUBSTRING_INDEX in SAP HANA. But you have a work around alternative by creating a function to pass the input string and delimiter.

And I am assuming that -2 in SUBSTRING_INDEX and providing the solution

Reverse the string and get the position of the second delimiter, '-' in your case, into "obtainedPosition"

Now subtract that "obtainedPosition" from the length of the string.

```
obtainedPosition = LENGTH(id) - obtainedPosition
```

Using that value in the inbuilt substring function you can get the required string and return it from the function.

```
SELECT SCHEMA.FN_SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,obtainedPosition) INTO ReturnValue FROM DUMMY;

CREATE FUNCTION FN_SUBSTRING_INDEX
(
  id VARCHAR(500),
  delim VARCHAR(2)
)
RETURNS SplitString VARCHAR(500)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE reversedString VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE charString VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE i INT := LENGTH(:id);
    DECLARE len INT := LENGTH(:id);
    DECLARE obtainedPosition INT := 0;
    DECLARE flag INT := 0;        
    reversedString := '';

    --loop to reverse the inputstring
    WHILE :i > 0
    DO
    reversedString = CONCAT(:reversedString, SUBSTRING(:id,:i,1));
    i := :i - 1;
    END WHILE;

    --loop to get the second delimiter position
    i := 1;
    WHILE :i <= :leng
    DO
        charString := '';
        charString := SUBSTRING(:reversedString,i,1);
        IF((:charString = :delim ) AND (:flag < 2)) THEN
            BEGIN
                obtainedPosition := :i;
                flag := :flag + 1;
            END;
        END IF;
        i := :i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    --IF condition to check if at least 2 delimiters are available, else print complete string
    IF(flag = 2) THEN
        obtainedPosition := :len - :obtainedPosition + 2; --2 is added to avoid the character at that position and '-' from printing
    ELSE
        obtainedPosition := 1;
    END IF;

    --SplitString contains the string's splitted return value   
    SELECT SUBSTRING(:id,:obtainedPosition) INTO SplitString FROM DUMMY;
END;
```

The above function is modified from http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sqlscript-reverse-string-function-in-sap-hana.aspx

For string functions in SAP HANA refer to this: http://www.sapstudent.com/hana/sql-string-functions-in-sap-hana/3

You can use anonymous block in SAP HANA to call and check the function

```
 DO 
 BEGIN
   DECLARE id VARCHAR(500) := 'Test-sam-ple-func';
   DECLARE delim VARCHAR(2) := '-';
   SELECT SCHEMA.FN_SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,delim) AS "SplitStringIndex" FROM DUMMY;
 END;
```

I would be glad to know reason for a downvote. :)